# JSON value inside href tag in react

Tags: json, reactjs

So I have a JSON where I'm fetching data.

Example of JSON:

```
  { 
        "postid": "123123, 
        "title": "title of post",
    }
```

I'm trying to add this id inside an href like `<a href="https://example.com/{data.post}">Post</a>` but it doesn't render, I get a https://example.com/{data.post} url in the frontend. (Doing `<p>{data.post}</p>` renders the post ID normally.)

Is there a way to get the field inside an href tag? Or should I make another field on my JSON with the full URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in a template literal as a normal value:

```
<a href={`https://example.com/${data.post}`}>Post</a>
```

Please see [these docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx) on how to pass attributes to a JSX element. The above is just simply a [Javascript tempalate liter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) passed in as a prop to the `<a>` tag.